# Tabbing wrong in nested commands

Tags: macros, indentation, nesting

So, I have two commands defined in my document class like this.

```
\newcommand{\skillgroup}[2]{
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{5mm} \= \kill
\sqbullet \>\+ \textbf{#1} \\
\begin{minipage}{\smallertextwidth}
\vspace{2mm}
#2
\end{minipage}
\end{tabbing}
}

\newcommand{\skilllang}[3]{
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{5cm}\=\hspace*{4cm}\= \kill
#1 \> #2 \> \textit{#3}
\end{tabbing}
}
```

The `\skillgroup` command is working properly if you put text in it however when in want to insert a sequence of tabbed content via the `\skilllang` command, the indent of the prior command seems to be escaped and the tabbed sequence starts at the beginning of the line rather than indented as simple text would be.

Use in main.tex:

```
\skillgroup{Software Engineering}{
\skilllang{Programing languages }{C\# / XAML, Java}{...}
}
```

Output is as seen in picture below.

[image: First one is with \skilllang and second is just plain text]

Comment: please provide a small complete document that shows the issue.

Comment: I provided the call in main.tex as well as a screenshot of the output at the end of the post.

Comment: yes but that is not helping anyone to help you.

Comment: it's a bit hard to guess what you want `\skillgroup` to do it's not really using the tabbing at all: the argument just goes in a minipage that's in the leftmost cell.

Comment: Okay, so i've meant the \skillgroup macro to work like a container in html or xaml which holds several \skilllang s. The latter is then looking like: cont1    cont2    cont3

Comment: With defined spacing between those. *

Comment: you still haven't provided a test file or the definitions of commands used in your fragments.

Comment: As of right now i am not allowed to mark my answer as solution but i will when i am able to. The test file you're asking me for really is irrelevant to this question. Standard LaTex document frame would be the deal here. Thank you for your time.

Comment: No it was not irrelevant, the fact that you did not provide a test file and the fact that no one but you could answer the question are not unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the implementation of the `tabbing`-environment in [source2e.pdf](https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e) it seems obvious that this environment is implemented in a way where nesting is **not** intended/is **not** possible. E.g., it is based on `\trivlist` without taking adding up of left margins when nested into account.

You can have LaTeX put things into a scratch-box and then use that scratch-box inside `tabbing`.

After doing some guesswork related to `\sqbullet` and `\smallertextwidth` and the usage of the `mathabx`-package  I can come up with the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\newbox\myscratchbox
\makeatletter
\newcommand\createmyscratchbox[1]{%
  \setbox\myscratchbox\vtop{%
    \hsize=\smallertextwidth
    \linewidth=\smallertextwidth
    \topsep=0pt %
    \partopsep=0pt %
    #1%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\newlength\smallertextwidth
\setlength\smallertextwidth{10cm}

\newcommand{\skillgroup}[2]{%
\begin{tabbing}%
\hspace{5mm} \= \kill
\ensuremath{\sqbullet} \>\+ \textbf{#1} \\
\begin{minipage}{\smallertextwidth}%
\vspace{2mm}%
#2%
\end{minipage}%
\end{tabbing}%
}

\newcommand{\skilllang}[3]{%
\begin{tabbing}%
\hspace*{5cm}\=\hspace*{4cm}\= \kill
#1 \> #2 \> \textit{#3}%
\end{tabbing}%
}%

\begin{document}

\createmyscratchbox{%
  \skilllang{Programing languages }{C\# / XAML, Java}{whatsoever}%
}%
\skillgroup{Software Engineering}{%
  \box\myscratchbox
}%

\skillgroup{Blubb Blubb}{Bla bla}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you can do everything in the same `tabbing`-environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\newcommand{\skillgroup}[2]{%
\begin{tabbing}%
\hspace*{5mm}\=\hspace*{5cm} \= \hspace*{4cm} \= \kill
\ensuremath{\sqbullet}\+\>\textbf{#1}\\
\rule{0mm}{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+2mm\relax}#2%
\end{tabbing}%
}


\newcommand\setbreakandhyphenationparameters{%
  \sloppy
}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\skilllang}[3]{%
  \vtop{\hsize=5cm \noindent\setbreakandhyphenationparameters\hspace{0pt}#1\hspace{0pt}\strut\hss\par}\>%
  \vtop{\hsize=4cm \noindent\setbreakandhyphenationparameters\hspace{0pt}#2\hspace{0pt}\strut\hss\par}\>%
  \settowidth\@tempdima{ }%
  \vtop{\hsize=\dimexpr\textwidth-5mm-9cm-2\@tempdima\relax\noindent\setbreakandhyphenationparameters\textit{\hspace{0pt}#3\hspace{0pt}}\strut\par}\\%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent A \hfill B

\skillgroup{Software Engineering}{%
  \skilllang{Programing languages}{C\# / XAML, \hfill Java}{whatsoever whatsoever whatsoever whatsoever}%
  \skilllang{Programing languages}{C\# / XAML, Java}{There should happen some line-breaking. There should happen some line-breaking.}%
  \skilllang{Programing languages 
             Programing languages 
             Programing languages}{C\# / XAML, Java}{whatsoever}%
}%

\skillgroup{Blubb Blubb}{Bla bla}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Good solution!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to work around this using a tabular environment. This is the solution for `\skilllang` from above. Use this way stays the same.

```
\newcommand{\skilllang}[3]{
\begin{tabular}{@{} m{4cm} m{4cm} m{6cm}}
{#1}  &  {#2} & {#3} 
\end{tabular}
\\
}
```